# Split windows file names into 3 parts and sort in different folders C#

Tags: c#, file, sorting, split, filenames

I am trying to write a C# to read in a list of files, and sort them accordingly. The list of files consists of a collection of music files, the files are structured such that the file name is: Name of Song, Artist, Album.mp3  The files should be placed in folders, such that: The top-level folder has the name of the Artist. The sub folders are the names of the various Albums. The files in the albums sub folder are just the name of the song.

Top Folder - Artist
Sub Folder - Albums from artist
Sub Folder - Songs from Album

FOR EXAMPLE:  SONG NAME-ARTIST-ALBUM.mp3
So where the dash appear needs to sort its song(SUBFOLDER OF ALBUM) that belongs to that album (SUBFOLDER OF ARTIST) and to that artist (TOP  LEVEL)

```
  string originalFiles = ("C:\\Users\\User1\\Downloads\\UnSortedMusicFolder");
                    //var hyphen = new char[] { '-' };
                    var orderedFiles = originalFiles.Select(fileName =>
                    {
                        // TODO: decide what to do if filename incorrect format
                        string[] splitFileName = originalFiles.Split('-');
        
                        int filecategory;
                        switch (splitFileName[2])
                        {
                            case "NameofSong":
                                filecategory = 0;
    //add logic 
                                break;
                            case "Artist":
                                filecategory = 1;
    //add logic 
                                break;
                            case "Album":
                                filecategory = 2;
    //add logic 
                                break;
                            default:
                                filecategory = 3;
                                break;
                        }
        
                        return new
                        {
                            FileYear = Int32.Parse(splitFileName[0]),
                            FilePeriod = filecategory,
                            OriginalFileName = fileName,
                        };
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IComparable like code below.  I used numbers so you can easily see results.  You can change the array of numbers to your filenames

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication19
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] input = {
                                 "5-4-3-2",
                                 "1",
                                 "1-1",
                                 "1-3",
                                 "1-2-4",
                                 "3-1-2-3",
                                 "3-1"
                             };
            string[] output = input.Select(x => new HyphenString(x)).OrderBy(x => x).Select(x => x.name).ToArray();
        }
        public class HyphenString : IComparable<HyphenString>
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            List<string> names { get; set; }
            
            public HyphenString(string name)
            {
                this.name = name;
                names = name.Split(new char[] { '-' }).ToList();
            }
            public int CompareTo(HyphenString other)
            {
                int results = 0;
                int minLength = Math.Min(names.Count, other.names.Count);

                for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++)
                {
                    results = this.names[i].CompareTo(other.names[i]);
                    if (results != 0) return results;
                }

                return names.Count.CompareTo(other.names.Count); ;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like how I did with the case statements?

Comment: Like when I used texts in my case statements? How would i replace the array?

Comment: The code does all the work.  Not sure what you mean by replacing array.The following will give the classes sort and you can get the split names from the classes. : var output = input.Select(x => new HyphenString(x)).OrderBy(x => x).ToList()

Comment: Thank you. FILENAME is declared as a const but not used, where can I use  FILENAME so that folder is tied back to the array structure?

Comment: what does CompareTo method? does it compare from the old string to the new string?

Comment: See the MSDN documenation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?force_isolation=true.  CompareTo() method is required.  When the OrderBy does a sort it compares two objects in the array and gets one of 3 results -1 : Right less than Left  0 : Left and Right are equal 1 : Right greater than Left.  THIS is the left side of comparison and OTHER is the right side.  The FILENAME was left over from a previous posting.